# Iterated Expectations problem

Tags: econometrics

Is this procedure correct?
$$E[y_{t-1}\epsilon_t]$$
$$= E[E[y_{t-1}\epsilon_t|y_{t-1}]]$$
$$=E[y_{t-1}E[\epsilon_t|y_{t-1}]]$$

Comment: A time index for the expectations operator would help.

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t know it.

Answer (score 2):

It appears correct to me.
The relevant Wikipedia page is here,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation